# Most pythonic way to convert to boolean?

Tags: python

What is the most pythonic way to convert to boolean based on the truthiness of the object?

`return bool(an_object)`

or

```
if an_object:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

or something else entirely?

In this instance we can't get by relying on the truthiness of the object.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you really **need** a boolean, use `bool(something)`...

However, usually you don't *need* a boolean so rather than `return bool(something)`, you can just `return something` and the user can then decide what context to use it in.

Answer (score 0):

Depending what you need, you can

```
 return not an_Object is None
```

or whatever your predicate is.  This will allow you to control which objects are True and which are None

Comment: `an_object is not None` is preferred: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations